# Using loop in jquery not work

Tags: jquery, arrays, for-loop

I want to use for loop to create jquery function, but when I add the array parameter in the string, it didn't work.
Any suggestion?

```
var ids=["width_uncheck","thickness_uncheck"];
var names=['width','thickness'];
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    $("#"+ids[i] ).click(function() {
        $('input:radio[name='+names[i]+']').each(function(i) {
            this.checked = false;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: For sure your name='+names... needs double quotes should read 'input:radio[name="'+names[i]+'"]')

Comment: In the second .each'-loop you use 'i' as index-variable ... use something else.

Comment: The reason is not the quotes. Because I change to 'input:radio[name='+names[0]+']' it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this because `i` has changed to it's maximum at the time the click event occurs.

You need to use a javascript closure which you can easily do with `$.each`

```
$.each(ids, function(i, id){
   $("#"+id ).click(function() {
        // no need for `each`, just use `prop()`
        $('input:radio[name='+names[i]+']').prop('checked',false);
    });
});
```

The difference here is that `i` is an argument of the function and therefore won't change it's value within the function the way it will in `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

You have error with selector with radio name you need to add quote sign there
You need to use `$('input:radio[name="'+names[i]+'"]')`

For ie

```
var ids=["width_uncheck","thickness_uncheck"];
var names=['width','thickness'];
for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
    $("#"+ids[i] ).click(function() {
        $('input:radio[name="'+names[i]+'"]').each(function(i) {
            this.checked = false;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: will still fail due to no closure for `i`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotes for the name in the selector.

You could also just use the jquery each function without an element for your array.

```
$.each(ids, function (i, value) {
    var ids=["width_uncheck","thickness_uncheck"];
    var names=['width','thickness'];

    $("#"+ids[i] ).click(function() {
        $('input:radio[name="'+names[i]+'"]').each(function(i) {
            this.checked = false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: if quotes are a problem (which they aren't), why are they not a problem in your second example?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add them in there. They are there now. I haven't tested the code as I should have before I answered, that's just what I noticed.